# Using a collection to store generics whose type implement a common interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a type:

```
ExcelSheet<T>
```

And I have Some types that implement an interface:

```
IAddress
public class Instructor :  IAddress
public class Student : IAddress
```

I would like to do the following.

```
....
ExcelSheet<Instructor> instructorSheet = GetSheet<Instructor>(); 
ExcelSheet<Student> student = GetSheet<Student>();

List<ExcelSheet<IAddress>> sheetsWithAddress = new List<ExcelSheet<IAddress>>
    {
        instructorSheet,
        student
    }
```

As written this is not possible.  I'm using c# 4.0
Is there a way for this to work?
Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can! This is covariance and it's a new feature in C# 4.0.

Read more here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: Note if you go this way, you'll need some refactoring ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you constrain the T in ExcelSheet to IAddress it will work.

```
class ExcelSheet<T> where T : IAddress
```

Comment: -1: This is not correct. His example still won't work, because `ExcelSheet<Instructor>` is something else than `ExcelSheet<IAddress>`. Covariance is the right way to go as Matias pointed out.